# How do I create a text file and add text to it in Git Bash?

Tags: git-bash

How do I create a text file and add text to it in Git Bash?

Is there a command for that operation?

Answer (score 7):

In git bash, the simplest way to create/write a file is:

```
echo "some text" > aNewFile
```

Then you can edit it:

```
vi aNewFile
```

Comment: Hi VonC. Thanks for your reply. Regards janiceg28

Answer (score 1):

### you can create any new file by using any Editor's command.

Now, there are many editors for git : vi, nano, gedit, etc..
Typing

```
nano hey.txt
```

or

```
vim hey.txt
```

will create new hey.txt in the git repository folder(if not already created) and will open the editor for you to edit your .txt file in simple text. Then save it and you are done !

Answer (score 1):

In git bash, the simplest way to create a file is:

```
touch README.md
```

it will create a Text file named README.md